# camer.start_preview() not working?

Tags: python

When I run my python script the contains:

```
import picamera
from time import sleep
camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.start_preview()
sleep(10)
camera.stop_preview()
```

The script just runs and shows no live feed. Is this supposed to happen, because everywhere I read this is wrong. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your screen configuration but I'll tell you this, as far as I know, camera preview only works on the screen attached to the raspberry pi directly, you cannot see the feed through vnc.

Comment: I use an lcd touchscreen. (PiTFT )

Comment: I don’t use VNC

Comment: It doesn't work with the PiTFT I think, unless you use the HDMI mirror option.